# how can I create buttons for values located inside an array, and that same array is located inside another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am currently struggling with creating buttons for values inside an array, which are also located insinde an array. For example:

```
let numbers = [{"allNum": ["0", "1", "2", "3","4"]}, {"evenNumbers": ["2", "4"]}];
```

So, in that array, lets say that I want to create buttons for all the values inside allNum. Also, I know that in order to create a button I can simply use the createElement statement. Will I need to use something like forEach() and a mix of createElement to achieve my goal?

Say for example, something like this?

```
// lets say I have a html element with an id of "li"
var liEl= document.querySelector ("li");
function createBtn (allnum) = { document.createElement("button")
liEl.appendChild (createBtn);
return createBtn;
};
numbers.forEach (createBtn)
```

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Requires a little formatting on your behalf but I think this is what you were after. You could of also gone down the foreach loop aswell :)

```
for (x in numbers[0].allNum) {
    let b = document.createElement("button");
    b.setAttribute('id', x);
    b.innerHTML = x;
    document.body.appendChild(b);
  }
```

Comment: You have enough reputation to ask clarifying questions in comments. Comments are exactly for that purpose. Please visit the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to see how Answers on Stack Overflow work.

Comment: @Scratte Yeah well it's my first time answering, and as helpful as this website is, it's really not user friendly, nor are most of the people on here.

Comment: You don't have to tell the author you've updated your Answer. I think they are notified of changes on their thread.. but, if you want to make it on the site. spending a weekend reading the [Help Center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q66PI.png) will be worth it. Stack Overflow isn't like a forum, so knowing what it's about and how it works will help you avoid the pitfalls :) (Assuming people are helpful and nice, even if they deliver their messages a little rough, will also make it easier here :-)

Comment: @Scratte I know mate, found out the hard way! On a personal ban myself, but thank you for the heads up!

Comment: @Scratte Thanks, I will take my time and check stackoverflow rules regarding posting and answering.

Comment: @KyrinP Maybe [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) isn't the worst place to start :)

Comment: @KyrinP no problem, dont forget to leave it as answered :)